# Calculate checksum for a directory

Tags: linux, directory, checksum

i need to calculate a checksum for a directory in question.

It should return one number for this directory, not for each file inside it.

Can you, quys, help me with it ?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to checksum? The directory information (filenames, inode numbers), or also the file meta information (modification times etc) or also the file contents or what? Under what circumstances do you expect the directory to have a different checksum?

Comment: Calculate checksums for each file, for the metadata and XOR it all. Do this recursively if necessary.

Comment: @Paul, i need to make sure, that nobody has changed the files in a directory in question.

Comment: Then just checksum each file and sum the results? Does your definition of "changed the files" include changes to permissions, creation/modification dates, owner/group etc?

Comment: Yes. I think, i can also just take a sum of all the results. I'm playing with the "cat" command, but, no success right now. I say following: "find ./crc_test/ -type f | cat | crc32", but i does't work.

Comment: cat is doing precisely nothing there. You probably meanbt "find ./crc/test/ -type f | xargs cat | crc32'?

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use `tar` to do this. Something like `tar -c dir/ | md5sum -b`, although you may need to play with the options to `tar` so it doesn't include access times (which would mess up the checksum if somebody accesses the files in that directory, even without modifying any of them).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [md5deep](http://md5deep.sourceforge.net/). From its [homepage](http://md5deep.sourceforge.net/):

> md5deep is a set of programs to compute MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256, Tiger, or Whirlpool message digests on an arbitrary number of files.

I haven't used it myself, but from what I gather it's pretty much a collection of multi-file versions of md5sum, sha256sum and similar checksum tools from [GNU Coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/).